# Overloading in Varargs Methods

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

```
public class OverloadingVarargsMethodWithNormalMethod {

     static void a(int... c){
         System.out.println(c.length);
         for(int array:c){
            System.out.println(array);
         }
     }  

    static void a(int d,int e,int f){  
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println(f);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         a(1,2,3);
    }
}
```

I expected to take an ambiguous error.But,the code runs second " a " method.Why?Are two methods suitable for a(1,2,3)?

Comment: The compiler prefers the method that has the right explicit arguments. It will fall back on the varargs method if there isn't a non-varags match. This lets you provide methods for cases of particular numbers of arguments if you need to.

Comment: See [JLS 15.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2): vararg invocations are considered last, in phase 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most specific function definition will be called. `int a, int b, int c` is more specific than `int...  c`.

For the same reason the following is valid

```
static void foo(String a) {

}
static void foo(Object a) {

}
```

and the first would be called for `foo("bar");`

Further reading here: https://blogs.oracle.com/mcimadamore/entry/testing_overload_resolution